# In Spark Java how can I programmatically determine the number of *active* cores and tasks?

Tags: apache-spark

The Spark web UI displays great information about the total and active number of cores and tasks.  How can I get this information programmatically in Java Spark so that I can display job progress to end users?

I did read about the "append /json/" trick to extract JSON versions of web UI pages from the master, and I can get the *total* number of cores that way...

But all the information about *active* cores and tasks seems to be in the driver UI pages.  I tried the "/json/" trick on the driver UI pages and it  just redirects me back to the HTML pages.

Comment: On vanilla spark/ EMR, which does not have auto-scaling the number of cores will be constant through the life cycle of the application. You can get the active Spark jobs, stages and tasks through `SparkStatusTracker`: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.SparkStatusTracker

Comment: Ah thank you Sai, SparkStatusTracker looks like exactly what I need.  We also found the REST API for driver JVMs -- once we figure out how to cure the exceptions that is generating, that looks like another way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like we have discovered two different ways to reveal this information:

1) Retrieve the SparkStatusTracker from the SparkContext (thank you Sai):

```
JavaSparkContext javaSparkContext = ...;
JavaSparkStatusTracker javaSparkStatusTracker = javaSparkContext.statusTracker();
for (int stageId : javaSparkStatusTracker.getActiveStageIds()) {
  SparkStageInfo sparkStageInfo = javaSparkStatusTracker.getStageInfo(stageId);
  int numTasks = sparkStageInfo.numTasks();
  int numActiveTasks = sparkStageInfo.numActiveTasks();
  int numFailedTasks = sparkStageInfo.numFailedTasks();
  int numCompletedTasks = sparkStageInfo.numCompletedTasks();
  ...
}
```

2) Consult the REST API available from the driver JVM:

https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/monitoring.html#rest-api