# Spark Java programmatically mark task as failure

Tags: apache-spark, retry-logic

As spark provides the feature of job failure detection and retries mechanism, I want to use this feature for my code, which means for some scenarios I want to mark spark Job as failed and then spark will retry that job again.
I tried to find out the Job/Stage status, I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55731918/in-spark-java-how-can-i-programmatically-determine-the-number-of-active-cores). And implemented:

```
JavaSparkContext jsc = JavaSparkContext.fromSparkContext(this.spark.sparkContext());
        JavaSparkStatusTracker statusTracker = jsc.statusTracker();
        for(int jobId: statusTracker.getActiveJobIds()) {
             SparkJobInfo jobInfo = statusTracker.getJobInfo(jobId);
             for(int stageId: jobInfo.stageIds()) {
                 SparkStageInfo stageInfo = statusTracker.getStageInfo(stageId);
                 LOGGER.warn("Stage id=" + stageId + "; name = " + stageInfo.name()
                    + "; completed tasks:" + stageInfo.numCompletedTasks()
                    + "; active tasks: " + stageInfo.numActiveTasks()
                    + "; all tasks: " + stageInfo.numTasks()
                    + "; submission time: " + stageInfo.submissionTime());
            }
        }
```

here, I am able to find out job/task/stage status but is there any way(API) to mark spark job as failed? Also, Is it a good approach to implement a retry mechanism instead of writing custom code for retry?

Answer (score 1):

In other words you want to re-schedule already successfully completed job, right?

While `SparkContext` provides API to [cancel job by ID](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/org/apache/spark/SparkContext.html#cancelJob(jobId:Int):Unit) there's no similar API to re-run it.

However, it provides two low-level APIs to execute a custom job:

- synchronous [runJob](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/org/apache/spark/SparkContext.html#runJob%5BT,U%5D(rdd:org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD%5BT%5D,processPartition:Iterator%5BT%5D=%3EU,resultHandler:(Int,U)=%3EUnit)(implicitevidence$16:scala.reflect.ClassTag%5BU%5D):Unit)
- asynchronous [submitJob](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/org/apache/spark/SparkContext.html#submitJob%5BT,U,R%5D(rdd:org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD%5BT%5D,processPartition:Iterator%5BT%5D=%3EU,partitions:Seq%5BInt%5D,resultHandler:(Int,U)=%3EUnit,resultFunc:=%3ER):org.apache.spark.SimpleFutureAction%5BR%5D)

For both you need to provide `RDD` you want to re-process and a function to process partition.

But the easier option would be just to re-run your action that started the job again if you know which one you need to.